# using Javascript to set Java fields

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

Setting variables directly in Java classes doesn't seem to be working.  Why not?  What is the proper syntax?  Where does the variable go??

The following prints out 2 and 1. Thus the `f.x=2;` never happened according to the object `f` of `Foo`.

```
@Test
    public void testJS2Java() throws IOException, ScriptException, Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();// create JavaScript engine
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        class Foo {
            int x = 1;
        }
        Foo f = new Foo();
        engine.put("f", f);
        System.out.println(engine.eval("f.x=2;"));
        System.out.println(f.x);
    }
```

The `f.x=2;` executes without error but which `x` was set?

Comment: I think that the first println is getting the `f` from the class that is now instantiated inside javascript engine. And the second one is getting the class that was instantiated directly in java. That's why the second print is not evaluating to 2 (that's just my guess).  btw, is that your question?

Comment: Different result when `Foo` is defined outside the method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues with your test:

1. Nashorn allows access only to **public** members of public classes (from
   exported modules for jdk9+) only. The local class Foo is
   not public. So its members are not accessible from JavaScript.
2. Nashorn allows access to **static** members only from "Java type
   objects" and not from instances of Java types. (**different from Java**).
3. Nashorn would ignore property sets on Java object if **no** public
   field or public bean property with appropriate setter is found.

A working sample demonstrating access to a static Java field from Nashorn:

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Main {
    public static int x = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngine e = new ScriptEngineManager().
            getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        // access type object for Java class "Main" using Java.type
        e.eval("var M = Java.type('Main');");

        // access public static field 'x' of Main class
        e.eval("print(M.x)");

        // assign to public static field 'x' of Main class
        e.eval("M.x += 10;");

        // change is seen from Java
        System.out.println(Main.x);
    }
}
```